# unable to convert parameter to apex type got arraylist

Tags: javascript, controller, sobject, remote-action

Is there a way to pass a sObject with RemoteAction from JavaScript to Apex?

**I want to create a bunch of sObjects. What is the right way to pass their information from JS to Apex with RemoteAction?**

What I tried is populating a JS object. And then pass its value to the apex controller. Here's how I populate the js object:

```
stockObject.Location__c = $j('.select-store-div option:selected').val();
stockObject.Product__c = productsArray[key]['Name'];
stockObject.LocationRetailPrice__c = productsArray[key]['newPrice'];
```

However it says it's unable to convert the types(expecting sObject, got arraylist). Is there a way to pass a sObject as a whole to the controller rather than a list of strings?

Comment: Product__c and LocationRetailPrice__c needs to be strings or Ids I believe.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - I put a .toString() to all of these and it still gave me the same error. I want to create a bunch of sObjects. What is the right way to pass their information from JS to Apex with RemoteAction?

Comment: Here is good sample on how this works http://th3silverlining.com/2012/06/22/salesforce-javascript-remoting-using-apex-and-javascript-objects-to-pass-data-from-client-to-server-side-and-vice-versa/

Comment: Why not `Remote Objects`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - I haven't used Remote Objects. Can you link me to what you mean?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - That worked, thank you. If you post it as an answer below I will accept it as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to bring up [one alternative](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_example_simple.htm) so you know about it: `Remote Objects`. Whether to use `@RemoteAction` or this alternative requires a more nuanced understanding of your use case  than I can glean from your post. However, the gist of how they work is below:

```
<apex:page>

    <!-- Remote Objects definition to set accessible sObjects and fields -->
    <apex:remoteObjects >
        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Warehouse__c" jsShorthand="Warehouse" 
            fields="Name,Id">
            <apex:remoteObjectField name="Phone__c" jsShorthand="Phone"/>
        </apex:remoteObjectModel>
    </apex:remoteObjects>

    <!-- JavaScript to make Remote Objects calls -->
    <script>
        var fetchWarehouses = function(){
            // Create a new Remote Object
            var wh = new SObjectModel.Warehouse();

            // Use the Remote Object to query for 10 warehouse records
            wh.retrieve({ limit: 10 }, function(err, records, event){
                if(err) {
                    alert(err.message);
                }
                else {
                    var ul = document.getElementById("warehousesList");
                    records.forEach(function(record) {
                        // Build the text for a warehouse line item
                        var whText = record.get("Name");
                        whText += " -- ";
                        whText += record.get("Phone");

                        // Add the line item to the warehouses list
                        var li = document.createElement("li");
                        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(whText));
                        ul.appendChild(li);
                    });
                }
            });
        };
    </script>

    <h1>Retrieve Warehouses via Remote Objects</h1>

    <p>Warehouses:</p>

    <ul id="warehousesList">
    </ul>
    <button onclick="fetchWarehouses()">Retrieve Warehouses</button>

</apex:page>
```

**Creating Records**

A better example might be [Creating Records with Remote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using_create.htm):

```
var ctDetails = { FirstName: 'Marc', LastName: 'Benioff' };
var ct = new RemoteObjectModel.Contact();
ct.create(ctDetails, function(err) {
    if(err) { 
        console.log(err);
        alert(err.message);
    }
    else {
        // this is the contact
        console.log(ct.log());     // Dump contact to log
        console.log(ct.get('Id')); // Id is set when create completes
    }
});
```

Comment: Very interesting! In my case I was passing a sObject which I would insert through the controller. Can I insert through js using remote objects?

Comment: @Arthlete Definitely. Added a better example. You should peruse the links in the left navigation. Great learning experience even if you don't use them this time.

Comment: That's so awesome! Thank you for opening my eyes to something new. I will refactor my code right now and give this a try.

Comment: Can I pass an array of objects to be created? Cannot find the syntax for that.

Comment: @Arthlete I think so. Can't find it on mobile but I will look later.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying different things but nothing works. The reason I want to pass a whole array of objects is to avoid hitting limits.